# Variants of rigid monoidal category for infinite dimensional spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory, monoidal-categories

It is well-known that the notion of a [rigid monoidal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rigid+monoidal+category) does not interact well with infinite-dimensional spaces.  To be more precise, the category of all vector spaces is not rigid, see for example [question 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510070/rigid-structure-for-the-category-of-infinite-dimensional-vector-spaces) or [question 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3236732/vector-spaces-are-not-rigid/3236773#3236773).

> Are there any related and/or weaker notions of "rigid monoidal category" which would allow consideration of infinite dimensional vector spaces (for example) in some sense?

I am not a category theorist, but have a functional analysis background.  I would be very happy to have an answer which used extra structure on the spaces (e.g. topology? a (complete) inner-product?)

**Update:** For example, consider the category of Banach spaces with bounded linear maps (or contractions, if you prefer) and the [projective tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_tensor_product) to obtain a symmetric monoidal category.  This *nearly* satisfies the conditions to be a [star-autonomous category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/star-autonomous+category) with the usual Banach space dual, as it is true that
$$ \mathcal B(E \widehat\otimes F, G^*) \cong \mathcal B(E, (F\widehat\otimes G)^*). $$
However, the map $*$ is only a faithful functor, not full, as $\mathcal B(E,F) \rightarrow \mathcal B(F^*,E^*), T\mapsto T^*$ is not surjective, in general.  I think one can get further by using the [Chu construction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chu+construction).

*However*, somehow this example feels wrong to me.  I think the reason why is that I'd like to:

> Capture both the evaluation ($X^*\otimes X\rightarrow 1$) and coevaluation ($1\rightarrow X^*\otimes X$) maps, in some sense.

Comment: Your formula of Hom sets in the category of banach spaces seems wrong, the right hand side doesn't have any $G$.

Comment: @jeanmfischer: Thanks, fixed.

Comment: The coevaluation should capture the identity map : If you have an evaluation, you have a map $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(1, V^*\otimes V) \to \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(V,V)$, if you have a coevaluation, it should be in the preimage of the identity of $V$ under this map, for every object $V$. If you have that the identity is in the image of this map, you have your rigid monoidal structure. In the category of vector spaces, having a coevaluation is equivalent to having a finite generating family that you can extract from the preimage of the identity under this map.

Comment: You could have a look at [arxiv:1108.6020](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.6020) where they study a generalized notion of duality.